# (error) WRONGTYPE Key is not a valid HyperLogLog string value

Tags: redis

I am learning HyperLogLogs examples with redis-cli

> The redis-cli examples show how you can use HyperLogLog commands to record and count unique user visits to a website.
>   The command PFADD adds one or many strings to a HyperLogLog. PFADD returns 1 if the cardinality was changed and 0 if it remains the same:

[image]

Nonetheless, It report error when I follow the instructions:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> PFADD visits:2015-01-01 "carl" "max" "hugo" "arthur"
(error) WRONGTYPE Key is not a valid HyperLogLog string value.
```

Comment: Your `visits:2015-01-01` key already exists and is not an HLL - `DEL` it first.

Comment: ty, could you please transmit your short comment to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is, even if terse, quite informative - you are trying to use an existing key (i.e. `visits:2015-01-01`) that is not an HLL.

The existing key is possibly a string of some kind, but if you `DEL visits:2015-01-01`, you should be able to `PFADD` to it.